# MySQL does not convert string to int, despite casting it

Tags: mysql, casting, type-conversion, data-conversion

So what I am trying to do is to substract number of week from date, easy, right?

However, query returns a string I believe, because no matter how I try to sort it, it still gets sorted in that order: 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, ... 19, 2, 21

Of course I have googled, I have already tried CAST AS SIGNED/UNSIGNED/INT/DECIMAL. I did try to FORMAT it, multiply by one, add zero to result - nothing happens.

I use my query in BIRT - as I have managed to get it sorted in BIRT table, it still gets scrumbled in Workbench and BIRT charts - and it makes them look like nonsense.

Now as I write this post I see that the problem is that I have CASE there:

> SELECT CASE WHEN 2 = 1 THEN SUBSTR(mydate, 1, 7) ELSE CAST(WEEK(mydate, 0) AS SIGNED) END AS 'data' FROM mytable

Still: why does CAST not work when it's accompanied with CASE that might return a string? I wanted to conditionally let users choose whether the data is grouped by YYYY-MM (year and month) OR by weeks, now it seems I got kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

That casting (`CAST(WEEK(mydate, 0) AS SIGNED)`) looks unnecessary to me since [`week()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function returns week number in `INT`. So probably you can cast the result of `week()` to `varchar` since `substring` will result in `varchar`

```
CASE WHEN 2 = 1 THEN SUBSTR(mydate, 1, 7) ELSE CAST(WEEK(mydate, 0) AS CHAR(100)) END AS data 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: That's my problem, when I use your version, it sorts numbers in "string-like" order, so 0, 1, 10 and so on. It looks like using WEEK with CASE does not return number.

Comment: VARCHAR is not valid type. Basing on this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert
I have tried with CHAR/NCHAR, unfortunately without happy en - because they return strings.

Comment: @Marcin. ahh!! mistake ... it has to be `char`. see edit again

Comment: unfortunately, did not help, still returns string.

Comment: @Marcin, it will since other part of case returns string and thus I made it string by casting it

Comment: now I'm confused, if it was already returning string, how did casting it as string help me? I mean, the expected result was to either return YYYY-MM or number of week as a number - as far as I understand your solution only reassures that week is returned as string - which is the opposite of my question. Please correct me if I am wrong.